# scala for/yield on instance of class

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am scratching my head on an example I've seen in breeze's documentation about [distributions](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart#breezestatsdistributions).

After creating a Rand instance, they show that you can do the following:

```
import breeze.stats.distributions._

val pois = new Poisson(3.0);
val doublePoi: Rand[Double] = for(x <- pois) yield x.toDouble
```

Now, this is very cool, I can get a Rand object that I can get `Double` instead of `Int` when I call the `samples` method. Another example might be:

```
val abc = ('a' to 'z').map(_.toString).toArray
val letterDist: Rand[String] = for(x <- pois) yield {
val i = if (x > 26) x % 26 else x
abc(i)
}
val lettersSamp = letterDist.samples.take(20)
println(letterSamp)
```

The question is, what is going on here? `Rand[T]` is not a collection, and all the for/yield examples I've seen so far work on collections. The scala docs don't mention much, the only thing I found is translating for-comprehensions in [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield#translating-for-comprehensions).
What is the underlying rule here? How else can this be used (doesn't have to be a breeze related answer)

Comment: LIke mentioned in the link, a for comprehension is basically syntactic sugar for a combinations of `flatMap`s and one `map`.  You can write a for comprehension because [`Poisson`](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/#breeze.stats.distributions.Poisson) implements both `flatMap` and `map`. In your case the for comprehension is analogous to `pois.map(_.toDouble)`.

Comment: Also, a random distribution *is* a collection. It's a rather strange collection, that **maybe** contains **each** element instead of **definitely** containing **specific** elements, but you can interpret it as a collection. (A Bloom filter is an even weirder one, if you think about it.)

Answer (score 1):

Scala has rules for translating `for` and `for-yield` expressions to the equivalent `flatMap` and `map` calls, optionally also applying filters using `withFilter` and such. The actual specification for how you translate each for comprehension expression into the equivalent method calls can be found in [this section](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) of the Scala Specification.

If we take your example and compile it we'll see the underlying transformation happen to the `for-yield` expression. This is done using `scalac -Xprint:typer` command to print out the type trees:

```
val letterDist: breeze.stats.distributions.Rand[String] = 
        pois.map[String](((x: Int) => {
          val i: Int = if (x.>(26))
            x.%(26)
          else
            x;
          abc.apply(i)
}));
```

Here you can see that `for-yield` turns into a single `map` passing in an `Int` and applying the `if-else` inside the expression. This works because [`Rand[T]` has a `map` method](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/stats/distributions/Rand.scala#L94) defined:

```
def map[E](f: T => E): Rand[E] = MappedRand(outer, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

For comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for flatMap, map and withFilter. The main requirement for use in a for comprehension is that those methods are implemented.  They are therefore not limited to collections E.g. some common non-collections used in for comprehensions are Option, Try and Future.

In your case, Poisson seems to inherit from a trait called Rand

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/stats/distributions/Rand.scala

This trait has map, flatmap, and withFilter defined.

Tip: If you use an IDE like IntelliJ - you can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> on your for comprehension, and chose convert to desugared expression and you will see how it expands.